# How to use shell to derive an IPv6 address from a MAC address?

Tags: sed, awk, ipv6, mac-address

We know that we can use the MAC address to create an interface identifier, e.g. for a link-local IPv6 address which should be unique in the Network.

The image shows the way to do this:

[image: Create interface identifier from MAC address]

My questions are:

- How can I create an IPv6 address from a MAC using `awk` or `sed`?
- OR is there any command that gives me the link-local IPv6 address for a specific MAC (something like that `createIPv6 myMAC`)?

Comment: I rephrased your question a bit (pending review). IPv6 addresses are not *extracted* from MAC addresses, but created. And here you deal only with the interface identifier part (the last 64 bit) of an IPv6 address. But I'm not sure: Do you only want the interface identifier or a whole IPv6 address? Please re-edit, if I did not understand you correctly.

Comment: @Dubu, Thanks for editing, I want the whole IPv6 address.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want to create a whole IPv6 address from a MAC (and a given prefix), you could use the excellent `ipv6calc` tool by Peter Bieringer.

The following command creates a link-local IPv6 address (`fe80::` prefix) from a MAC address:

```
$ ipv6calc --action prefixmac2ipv6 --in prefix+mac --out ipv6addr fe80:: 00:21:5b:f7:25:1b
fe80::221:5bff:fef7:251b
```

You can leave most of the options away and let the command guess what to do:

```
$ ipv6calc --in prefix+mac fe80:: 00:21:5b:f7:25:1b
No action type specified, try autodetection...found type: prefixmac2ipv6
fe80::221:5bff:fef7:251b
```

For Debian distros, `ipv6calc` is in the main repository.

Answer (score 4):

From the [IPv6 Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_address#Modified_EUI-64) entry a more textual description:

> A 64-bit interface identifier is most commonly derived from its 48-bit MAC address.
>
> A MAC address 00:0C:29:0C:47:D5 is turned into a 64-bit EUI-64 by inserting FF:FE in the middle: 00:0C:29:FF:FE:0C:47:D5.

So replacing the third `:` with `:FF:FE:` should do the trick:

```
echo  00:0C:29:0C:47:D5 | sed s/:/:FF:FE:/3
00:0C:29:FF:FE:0C:47:D5
```

No idea if that syntax is specific to GNU sed.

---

Work in progress:

Convert that to bits:

```
for HEX in $(tr ":" " " <<< 00:0C:29:FF:FE:0C:47:D5) 
  do 
    printf "%08d " $(bc <<< "ibase=16;obase=2;$HEX") 
  done
```

should result in the bits `00000000 00001100 00101001 11111111 11111110 00001100 01000111 11010101` leaving only the flipping of bit number 7.

Comment: what about reverse the 7-th bit !

Comment: Ah the U/L bit, good point!

Answer (score 3):

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
import sys
n=[int(x, 16) for x in sys.argv[1].split(":")]
print "fe80::%02x%02x:%02xff:fe%02x:%02x%02x" % tuple([n[0]^2]+n[1:])
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a **bash function** (and place it in your `~/.bashrc`) that uses `IFS` to split the MAC address into 6 colon-separated groups and assembles them. You'll also need to flip the 7th most significant bit, i.e. bit 1 of the first byte:

```
mac_to_ipv6_ll() {
    IFS=':'; set $1; unset IFS
    echo "fe80::$(printf %02x $((0x$1 ^ 2)))$2:${3}ff:fe$4:$5$6"
}
```

Usage example:

```
$ mac_to_ipv6_ll 12:34:56:78:90:12
fe80::1034:56ff:fe78:9012
```

Answer (score 0):

I must give kudos to @rubo77 above for a pure-shell (unless you count printf) answer above, which I was seeking.

This adds a bit of sed to:

(a) elide any leading zeroes in each 16-bit chunk; and

(b) elide any further all-zero chunks at the start of the IID

...as per common conventions for address brevity.

```
mac_to_eui64() {
 IFS=':'; set $1; unset IFS
 echo "fe80::$(printf %x $((0x$1 ^ 2)))$2:${3}ff:fe$4:$5$6" |
  sed -E 's/:0+/:/g; s/:{3,}/::/; s/:$/:0/'
}
```

Note that if you wished to repurpose this for other (arbitrary) prefixes, which you might since EUI-64 can be used in any scope (although it's advised not to use it for global addresses for privacy reasons), you'd need a slightly more convoluted sed script. That's because the `fe80::` prefix already contains three zero-chunks (elided to the double-colon) adjacent to the start of the IID.  Thus even if the IID's first chunk is all-zeroes (that is, if the MAC started with `02:00`), it would be elided too. The EUI-64 format only leaves one further chunk that could be all-zero -- the last one -- which the script above adds back in as a single zero.  Other prefixes might require one to leave a single zero between two colons.

Comment: You're right, thanks - I went back and left @rubo77's fine `printf` alone and did the additional stuff in sed instead.